# How to set an element to show on medium screen and below in Tailwind?

Tags: responsive-design, tailwind-css

I have a div with a class of `hidden md:block` housing this element from heroicon:
`<MenuIcon class="ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-gray-500"/>`.

Currently, the div element only show when the screen size is at `md`, but I want to show at `md` **and** below, how exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tailwind breakpoints are mobile first, so they go UP. At first everything is visible.

You just need to hide elem. from some size and up:

***sm*** -> ***md*** -> ***lg*** -> ***xl*** -> ***2xl***

`class="lg:hidden"` will hide element from ***lg*** and above - *lg, xl, 2xl*

---

For more info about the topic look at: [Responsive design in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design)

Comment: Yea, I was just wondering when I was looking through the docs. So I can't manually reverse the order then?

Comment: Only if you redefine breakpoints in config and I would not recommend it since TW is designed around mobile first approach ;)

https://gist.github.com/heytulsiprasad/e8bae1eba7b90ef66b8b1b1ae0861d96

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are doing it in reverse.

Basically =>
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

> Where this approach surprises people most often is that to style
> something for mobile, you need to use the unprefixed version of a
> utility, not the sm: prefixed version. Don’t think of sm: as meaning
> “on small screens”, think of it as “at the small breakpoint“.

So you would have to do `class="block lg:hidden"` in your classes for it to work as you are describing :)

Comment: Great! Thanks bud!